# Alter DEFINER for specific stored procedure in place?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I've seen a few places where it's shown how to alter the definer for multiple stored procedures. I have one SP 'this_stored_procedure' that I want to change the definer from what it's set to now to something different.

```
UPDATE `mysql`.`proc` p SET definer = 'YournewDefiner' WHERE definer='OldDefinerShownBefore'
```

I tried this command and it altered the definer for any procedure that had the old user. I want to be able just to change the definer for one SP without changing the others. Is there a way to isolate the above query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose you could just filter add more conditions to your where clause to limit which definer is changed.

i.e.

```
update `mysql`.`proc` set `definer`='yournewdefiner' where name='yourstoredprocedurename'
and db='yourdatabasename';
```

I can't say whether you should do this or not, but with full rights I was able to update the definer on a specific stored procedure this way.

I would suggest to first check the matching records with a select before updating. As well to confirm the change after the update.

```
   select * from `mysql`.`proc` where name='yourstoredprocedurename'
    and db='yourdatabasename';
```

Comment: I tried this on my database and the command did not return an error, but I don't see that the definer actually got changed, even after I flushed privileges.

Comment: Not sure why it didn't work the first time, but I selected it first to make sure it was returning properly and then ran the update and I can see that it's changed. Thank you!

Comment: whar is proc? Is this my database?